# jQuery select closest tr

Tags: jquery

Hello I'm having some issues geting a `tr` toggled this is the code I have this is the HTML:

```
<table class="avs" border="1" width="384px">
    <tr class="avs">
        <th>Avatar name</th>
        <th >Position</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='avs'>
        <td>
            <a class='extralink' href="#"></a>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='extra'>
        <td colspan='2' >
            <div>
                <div>info</div>
                <div>image</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

This is the jquery:

```
$('.extralink').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.extra').toggle();
});
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: For the code we need to know where the link is you trigger the function on since you define position related functions like .next()

Comment: Well, this works: http://jsfiddle.net/VThEJ/

Comment: @Martin, the link is in the one of the table cells > <td class='avs'><a class='extralink' href="#"> </a></td>

Comment: This works to : http://jsfiddle.net/sh7ME/ , but you need to have something to click, right now your link has no content.

Comment: You maybe want to rethink your classes as well they seem a bit redundant.

Comment: it isn't working in my document very strange :/

Comment: Did you wrap the code in document.ready and include jQuery ?

Comment: oh i feel so stupid , i forgot to wrap it into document.ready

Comment: how would i get the rows that where toggled to close when another is togled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.extralink').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().next().toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I think his approach with .closest() is better in that case. If he wraps the link in in the future for example he'll have to change the selector.

Comment: -1 is a bit harsh as its actually not wrong. maybe he prefers performance over irrelevance @Andy google YAGNI

Comment: @BobTodd - this does exactly the same as the code posted in the question for this particular example, the only difference is that the OP used a more appropriate function (closest).

Comment: @andy yes, you are right! You posted a good working example on fiddle above. alternatively you could use .parents() combined with .yourclass:first

Comment: @BobTodd i didn't -1 him. I didn't say his solution is wrong, only that closest is actually more elegant in that case.

Comment: in most browsers closest() is slower than parent() :) but code look nicer

Comment: @Martin -  but then again, using `parents()` is'nt really an answer, as `closest()` is more efficient, and it would be just to repeat the code posted in the question, and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine... Check this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s35SP/)**

Comment: yes thank you, i found out that i forgot to wrap it into document.ready